# PHP PDO fetch and foreach - I'm not getting the first column

Tags: php, foreach, pdo, fetch

This is my first post, so I'm just getting to know how the community works so I can be helpful too, later on...

I have an **index.php** and **db.php** for testing PDO in a very small and simple app, in the first one goes the html and the second the database connection.

**index.php**

```
 <h1><?php echo $fjoin_bookname; ?></h1>
    <?php foreach($join as $j): ?>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <?php echo 'Page: '. $j['pageNumber']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $j['pageNote']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**db.php**

```
//get books and pages Join
    $query='SELECT * 
            FROM books
                INNER JOIN pages
                ON books.bookID = pages.bookID
            ORDER BY pageNumber ASC';

    $join = $db->query($query);
    $fjoin = $join->fetch();
    $fjoin_bookname = $fjoin['bookName'];
```

It is an app that gets page numbers with a corresponding note from a book, this will help to keep track of several books while on different devices.

**Problem:** 
I'm not getting the first row from the 'pages' table.
It was working fine until I inserted the fetch method

```
$fjoin = $join->fetch();
$fjoin_bookname = $fjoin['bookName'];
```

**Question**
Would anyone be so kind to help me work this out?

Comment: Does it work if you add `<table>` and `</table>` tags around your foreach?  In other words...  are you sure that it's not outputting at all, or is it just not rendering in your HTML browser?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not the full html I was just showing tr and td, but yes they are inside a table. THe answer from a.tereschenkov is the one that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a call of

```
$join->fetch()
```

it returns item from current position and move cursor to the next one.
You can fetch all elements to a var and then get fjoin_bookname from the first element:

**db.php**

```
//get books and pages Join
$query='SELECT * 
        FROM books
            INNER JOIN pages
            ON books.bookID = pages.bookID
        ORDER BY pageNumber ASC';

$statement = $db->query($query);
$join = $statement->fetchAll();
$fjoin = $join[0];
$fjoin_bookname = $fjoin['bookName'];
```

Comment: Great that was it!, it was going to the next with the 0 position it works great, thanks very much!!!